# R - List to data.frame using list names

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have this list:

```
structure(list(scaf = structure(1L, .Label = "HE638", class = "factor"), 
    pos = 8L, scaf = structure(1L, .Label = "HE638", class = "factor"), 
    pos = 8L, scaf = structure(1L, .Label = "HE638", class = "factor"), 
    pos = 8L), .Names = c("scaf", "pos", "scaf", "pos", "scaf", 
"pos"))
```

I want to get a data.frame so that the two columns are `scaf` and `pos`

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
do.call(rbind, poor.loci)
```

Desired result:

```
scaf     pos
HE638    8
HE638    8
HE638    8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are three options to consider:

***Option 1***

Straightforward selecting of every other element and manually creating your `data.frame`.

```
setNames(
  data.frame(unlist(poor.loci[c(TRUE, FALSE)], use.names = FALSE),
             unlist(poor.loci[c(FALSE, TRUE)], use.names = FALSE)),
  unique(names(poor.loci)))
#    scaf pos
# 1 HE638   8
# 2 HE638   8
# 3 HE638   8
```

***Option 2***

Convert your `list` into a "long" `data.frame` and `reshape` it to the form you want. Can also be done with the "reshape2" package using `melt` and `dcast` instead of `stack` and `reshape`.

```
X <- stack(lapply(poor.loci, as.character))
X$ID <- ave(X$values, X$values, FUN = seq_along)
reshape(X, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="ind")
#   ID values.scaf values.pos
# 1  1       HE638          8
# 3  2       HE638          8
# 5  3       HE638          8
```

***Option 3***

Rearrange your `list` and convert the rearranged `list` to a `data.frame`:

```
A <- unique(names(poor.loci))
data.frame(
  setNames(
    lapply(A, function(x) unlist(poor.loci[names(poor.loci) %in% x], 
                                 use.names = FALSE)), A))
```

Comment: one more: `as.data.frame(lapply(split(ll, names(ll)), unlist))`

Comment: @flodel Another one without `lapply` is: `as.data.frame(split(unlist(poor.loci), names(poor.loci)))`.